# R data.table set cellwise operation

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am trying to create a list of recursively applied scalars of a data.table and then save it into a list so I can mapply using a user defined function.

The dummy data is as follows:

```
   dt <- data.table(mtcars)[1,1:3]

     ncol(dt)
     cols <- colnames(dt)

     for(j in 1:ncol(dt)){

      dt_loop <- dt
      scaled_dt <- dt_loop[,j,with=FALSE]*(1+0.01)

      #drop scaled var
      dt_loop[ , (j) := NULL ]

      jj <- cbind(scaled_dt,dt_loop)

      #go back to original order
      setcolorder(jj,cols)

      assign(paste('dt_', j, sep=''),jj, envir = .GlobalEnv)

     }
```

And then I want to save all permutations assigned i.e `dt_1`, `dt_2` and `dt_3` into a single list, with list names set programmatically through `paste0`.

I tried using the `set` operator for `data.table` but I am failing.

In general, what I am doing seems very inefficient and there should be a proper way of achieving the recursive expansion from a single data.table into a list of data.tables in which the elements are slightly altered.

Bonus points if an extra row can be created for each `dt_1`, `dt_2` and `dt_3` which describes the operation conducted to each element. So for `dt_1` it would be a character `"mpg_+1%"`

```
   mpg    cyl disp Delta
1: 21.21   6  160  mpg_+1%
```

and the final list would look like this:

```
dt_list <- list(dt_1 = dt_1,
                dt_2 = dt_2, 
                dt_3 = dt_3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lapply(names(dt), function(col)
         copy(dt)[, (col) := get(col)*1.01][, Delta := paste0(col, "_+1%")])
#[[1]]
#     mpg cyl disp   Delta
#1: 21.21   6  160 mpg_+1%
#
#[[2]]
#   mpg  cyl disp   Delta
#1:  21 6.06  160 cyl_+1%
#
#[[3]]
#   mpg cyl  disp    Delta
#1:  21   6 161.6 disp_+1%
```

Comment: I got it working yesterday but your solution is so much more elegant. Thank you eddi